# Android clear dialog cache

Tags: android, caching, dialog, screen, orientation

how can I force Android to clear it's dialog cache when screen orientation changes? The problem is there's a bug in Android which causes background Drawables with tileMode="repeat" not to be repeated after rotating the screen. I'm not interested in using removeDialog nor onPrepareDialog, because it would require putting additional code in every activity which use specific dialog.

Or maybe it's possible to tell android not to cache dialog at all?

Thanks

Comment: Silly me. The dialogs are recreated by default, but Drawables fail anyway so the question remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhhh, the problem lies in bug in Android which causes Drawables in dialog to fail to restore their tileMode when layout hasn't been completely initialized (that's when dialogs are restored). Setting tileMode manually solves the problem.